# KFold splitting of time series

Tags: time-series, regression, cross-validation

I have a fundamental question about train/test split for time series. Let me give a simple example to illustrate my question, which is actually related to a more complex problem.

#### Example

Suppose I have the following dataset and I want to learn to predict how fast a worker can perform a task, as given in the column *task_duration_minutes*:

| date | worker_id | task_id | task_duration_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 75 |
| 2010-01-01 | 2 | 2 | 75 |
| 2010-01-01 | 3 | 2 | 60 |
| 2010-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 2010-01-03 | 3 | 2 | 45 |
| etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... |

*(I also have a table with features related to the *worker_id*, and a table with features related to the *task_id* which I can join on this table, but the worker features and task features are not relevant for the problem.)*

Note that new workers can have their first task late in this time series, and the duration between tasks is not equal. Hence, it is presumably not the *date* column that is important but rather the number of times a certain worker has previously done a certain task. Let's feature-engineer the column *worker_task_experience* to extract that information:

| date | worker_id | task_id | task_duration_minutes | worker_task_experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 75 | 0 |
| 2010-01-01 | 2 | 2 | 75 | 0 |
| 2010-01-01 | 3 | 2 | 60 | 0 |
| 2010-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 2010-01-03 | 3 | 2 | 45 | 1 |
| etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... | etc... |

#### Question: How to properly split this dataset for cross validation

I see two options:

1. One could view this dataset as a time series for each *worker_id* and the common practice for time series is to train/test-split as [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#time-series-split).
2. However, the target *task_duration_minutes* is not considered to be dependent on the *date*, but rather on the *worker_task_experience*, and hence I can disregard the *date* column and view this problem as a regular regression problem, for which I can do a regular cross validation using e.g. [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold).

As long as I am certain that my features do not contain information about the future, I can't see 2) is not acceptable. What do you think?

I am looking forward to your input.

Comment: I want to make sure that I understand the question correctly. Given user_id, and task_id, you want to estimate the duration of the task, next time it is completed, is this right? If so, let's say you have a user_id and item_id with 100 tasks completed, would you need an ML model to predict 101st task completion or duration of 100th task is close enough? Also, I suspect the biggest error and perhaps the biggest value gain is in predicting durations for early tasks, 1st, 2nd, 3rd... but I don't see how it is possible to do that with the approach you suggested.

Comment: My true problem is more complicated and contain business problems that I cannot explain here, so forgive me if this example is not completely thought through. I hope my questions about time Series splitning is still clear. But to answer your question: I see your concern, since task_id now completely defines the task. However, in reality, I never see the exact same task beeing done but only similar tasks. So I never see 100 tasks completed by the same worker. The 101th task may have different external factors.